# jq: How to substitute "null" from the output?

Tags: json, null, jq

I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "SecurityGroups": [
        {
            "Description": "launch-wizard-6 created 2018-10-25T13:59:20.092+03:00",
            "GroupName": "launch-wizard-6",
            "IpPermissions": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "-1",
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": [],
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": []
                },
                {
                    "FromPort": 22,
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": [],
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "ToPort": 22,
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": []
                }
            ],
            "OwnerId": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "GroupId": "sg-054368f50a6b4fea4",
            "IpPermissionsEgress": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "-1",
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIpv6": "::/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": []
                }
            ],
            "VpcId": "vpc-6ea82a08"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I run the following jq command:

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-id ${group_id} --profile ${profile} --region ${region} --output json | jq -r '.SecurityGroups[].IpPermissions[] | [ (.FromPort|tostring), .IpProtocol, .IpRanges[].CidrIp // .UserIdGroupPairs[].GroupId // "" ] | @tsv'
```

I get the following output:

```
null    -1  0.0.0.0/0
22  tcp 0.0.0.0/0
```

I'd like to remove the null from the output, how can it be done?

Comment: That's what I've tried following the previous question you answered... but it still shows null: https://jqplay.org/s/2vZH7C_6Jp

Comment: `((.FromPort // "")|tostring)`?

Comment: Can you please create an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [fallback](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/354) for the `.FromPort` key:

```
.FromPort // ""
```

So the command becomes;

```
.SecurityGroups[].IpPermissions[] | [ (.FromPort // "" ?), .IpProtocol, .IpRanges[].CidrIp ] | @tsv
```

Which yields to

```
    -1  0.0.0.0/0
22  tcp 0.0.0.0/0
```

[Try it online!](https://jqplay.org/s/MnbJvQV6bL)

Comment: `((.FromPort? // "") |tostring)` should be more than enough, at least if the possibility of .FromPort having a value of `false` does not need to be distinguished.

Comment: @peak Thank you, I didn't saw that, but your completely right, it's not necessary, I've edited my answer.

Comment: The "?" in your current answer is in the wrong place, as you can see by running  `jq -n '[] | (.a // "" ?)'`